# How to expunge email from the Gmail "All Mail" directory over IMAP? (with Alpine e-mail)

Tags: command-line, email, imap, gmail, alpine-mail

Looking to [manually](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.mail.pine/c/RX0fc1j0Vw8/m/Ns-EizQmAQAJ) save quantities of e-mail in batches so that they're [deleted and expunged](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10783109/4531180) from Gmail to free up space.  From Alpine the error message received is:

```
[No messages expunged from folder "[Gmail]/All Mail"]
```

Moving these messages to Gmail/Trash will enable expunge to function correctly.  Presumably this is a safety feature of Google?  Preventing deletion of e-mail in the All Mail directory over IMAP would seem to be a configuration of Gmail.

Aside from running dovecot and postfix, are there other suggestions?

The mail as from Alpine:

```
                                                                                     Dir: [Gmail]/
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    All Mail[/]
    Chats[/]
    Drafts[/]
    Important[/]
    Sent Mail[/]
    Spam[/]
    Starred[/]
    Trash[/]
```

Comment: If your focus is on downloading and removing emails from server, I believe POP3 might make more sense. The default for POP3 is - AFAIK - to delete mails after downloading, i.e. exactly what you need.

Comment: gmail giveth with one hand, storage, and taketh with the other:  hard to backup.